# Is there an Observable which can make multiple 0 argument emissions?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an [Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html) which makes an emission every half second. When this Observable makes an emission, I do not care about the object which is emitted.

In this situation using a [Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html) is inadequate as a Completable can only make one zero argument emission.

This is what I am currently using, which works fine, but is imperfect

```java
compositeDisposable.add(
    Observable.interval(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .timeInterval()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap(longTimed -> {
        if (emissionBoolean) {
            //todo: find an observable that can emit 0 arguments
            return Observable.just(true);
            }
        return Observer::onComplete;
        })
    .subscribe(wishIWasAZeroArgumentBoolean -> {
        onTick();
        }));
```

this is what I want to have for my subscribe instead

```java
.subscribe(() -> {
    onTick();
}));
```

Comment: (_) is not that much of a blocker isnt it?

Comment: @Antoniossss nope it's not a blocker at all, just looking to see if something exists

Comment: why use Rx at all if you don't want to emit something ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody this is a simplified version of what I am working with. This is a question about rx Observables, not a question about whether or not to use rx

Comment: i can only comment on what you post

Comment: if you are just looking for an observer which can emit but you don't care for the emitted object, why not use a `Maybe` ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody so what method would I use to get out of the flatMap with a ```Maybe```?

```if (emissionBoolean) { return Maybe.whatMethodHere(); }```

Comment: why do you want flatMap if you dont care about emited result........there is nothing (important) to flap then,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a valid question. `Maybe` cannot be used because `Maybe` does not emit more than once. `_` can't be used as a parameter name in Java 9 or above.

There isn't a way you can send "empty" notifications. RxJava [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#nulls) suggests using `Object` in case you want to explicitly ignore the emitted value. For example:

```
compositeDisposable.add(
    Observable.interval(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .timeInterval()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap(longTimed -> {
        if (emissionBoolean) {
            //todo: find an observable that can emit 0 arguments
            return Observable.just(new Object());
        }
        return Observable.empty()
    })
    .subscribe(object -> { // you still need to declare though.
        onTick();
    }));
```

Also, the code can be cleaner if you can switch to Kotlin, because in Kotlin you don't need to explicitly declare the name of the parameter if there is only one parameter.

```
compositeDisposable.add(
    Observable.interval(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .timeInterval()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap {
        if (emissionBoolean) {
            Observable.just(Any())
        } else {
            Observable.empty<Any>()
        }}
    .subscribe {
        onTick()
    }
```

Comment: Definitely should be the accepted answer. There's no way to pass a null across according to the wiki link posted. Best to go with either Object (I think a boolean may be better though)